# rHipe mapreduce get file name being processed

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, filenames

I am sending in a directory into my mapreduce job with RHipe. Is there a way to get the current file being processed in the Mapper? I want to output that as my key. Thank you!

```
map <- expression({
   fileName <- "testing123" // ?????
     .....
    rhcollect(fileName, value)
})

z <- rhmr(map=map,reduce=NULL, inout=c("text", "text")
      ,ifolder=directoryName
      ,ofolder=outDirectory)
```

Comment: Would `file.info` indicate a "locked" file (column "mode")?

Answer (score 0):

filename <- Sys.getenv("mapred.input.file")

is the solution